# 2 activities appear next to each other depending on phone orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I am trying to make a stopwatch app that has `Buttons` that allow the user to *start*/*pause* the timer, *reset* the timer, and *record* a lap time.  I would also have a `Button` that when clicked would bring up a new view that contains the **lap times** in a `ScrollView`.

That screen would have a `Button` which would bring the user back to the **timer** as well.

This alone would be relatively simple to do, it would just be two separate `Activities`. However, when the phone shifts to landscape mode I would like both screens (the **timer** and the **lap times**) to be displayed next to each other.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I was thinking about just having one `Activity` with two `LinearLayouts` inside of it (one for the **stopwatch** screen and one for the **lap times**) and having the `Button` that would normally switch between `Activities` just change the transparency of one of the view so only one was visible?

I imagine there is an easier way to do this, and I'm not sure if this solution would allow me to display each screen side by side anyways.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to display two activities at once, but I can tell you how I would solve this problem:

I would start by creating the stopwatch layout and the lap times layout in their own dedicated layout files - so in this example, we have **/res/layout/layout_stop_watch**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- stopwatch views here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

...and **/res/layout/layout_lap_times**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- lap times views here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in **/res/layout/activity_main.xml**, we have the following for portrait mode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/root_viewFlipper"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- stopwatch views included in activity_lap_times layout -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_stop_watch" />

    <!-- lap time views included in activity_lap_times layout -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_lap_times" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

The `ViewFlipper` is there so we can call `ViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1)` to show the lap times layout when the user clicks the button to view the lap times. Simply call `ViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0)` to go back to the stop watch layout.

For landscape mode, we have a separate layout - **/res/layout-land/activity_main.xml**. This layout will automatically display in landscape mode, so we don't need to handle that programmatically. We can set it up like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_stopwatch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!-- stopwatch views included in activity_lap_times layout -->
        <include layout="@layout/layout_stop_watch" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_lap_times"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!-- lap time views included in activity_lap_times layout -->
        <include layout="@layout/layout_lap_times" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And that's it.

One thing to keep in mind is the `ViewFlipper` won't be used in landscape mode, so you'll want to check if it's null before setting the displayed child. Also keep in mind that switching from portrait to landscape will re-create your activity. If you want to save any of the view states, you can use `savedInstanceState`.

The advantage of doing it this way is that we don't have to write the code twice for the stopwatch and lap times layout, for portrait and landscape. Also, since we're using one activity for all of it, all the associated java code can reside in **MainActivity.java**.